# Getting "Rate Limit Exceeded" when trying to add new API Project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 27 API Projects currently set up on one Google User account, via https://console.developers.google.com.  I am needing to add more, but whenever I try I get the following error "Rate Limit Exceeded".  I can see from the Requests column that the current projects hardly make any requests at all.  I can't see why we would have hit any limit.   Is there a limit to the total number of Projects you can set up against one Google User account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 25 free projects to one google account.
[Source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=en#create)

> How many applications can I create with Google App Engine?
>
> Each account can host 25 free applications and an unlimited number of
>   paid applications. If you reach the free limit, you can delete
>   existing applications to create more. Note that you can't re-register
>   an application ID.